# font-size email mobile is too small on all clients

Tags: ios, mobile, outlook, gmail, html-email

Hi guys :D I have coded a email template and it works great overall but i'm have a few issues on mobile:

The font in general is rather small on all mobile clients (Gmail, Outlook, iOS Mail) and on the iOS client, the whole template seems to be broken where everything gets align to the left side and not the center.

my code is unfortunately too long for me to post this but I have put it on GitHub gist and attached the link :D

gist.github.com/Afarah92/a6aecfcb6c34c86cb071f3599669dc2a

Comment: Can you please post code so we can help debug this for you

Comment: my code is unfortunately too long for me to post this but I have put it on GitHub gist and attached the link :D 

https://gist.github.com/Afarah92/a6aecfcb6c34c86cb071f3599669dc2a

Comment: Your code requires some sort of proccesing to be viewed, therefore nobody can test this to help you.

Comment: I've taken a quick look at your code but it's so bloated, it's a little tough to see what is going on. Also the platform  tags aren't making it any easier as they will also hold information in them that could be causing issues. I ran that code through Litmus anyway and not seeing any font or alignment issues on any mobile email client.

Comment: I would suggest test sending this template somewhere you can export the code from and so the platform tags actually populate with actual content and then we can take a look.