# the divider line way too long on outlook

Tags: ios, outlook, html-email, email-client

I have coded an email template and it works great overall but I have an issue with the length of the divider line:

The divider is way too long when I send a test mail to my outlook mail but have the right length on all other mail clients.

```html
<table border="0" agrepeatingblock="active" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;" agid="greenline-development_group_2_block_11">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;padding:Block::Margin_top|INTEGER|0px 0 Block::Margin_bottom|INTEGER|0px;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;background-color:Block::Block_container|COLOR|transparent;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="vertical-align: top;">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="width:100%;" role="presentation">
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="width:100%; max-width:706px">
                                                    <![endif]-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;max-width:706px;Margin:0 auto;background-color:Block::Content_container|COLOR|transparent;" role="presentation">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;padding:${blockparam:Block::Padding_top|INTEGER|10}px 12px 0;" class="pt-10">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td align="center" style="vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 12px;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%;">
<tr>
<td
height="${blockparam:Block::Padding_bottom|INTEGER|10}"
style="border-top:${blockparam:Horizontal_rule::Size|INTEGER|1}px solid ${blockparam:Horizontal_rule::Color|COLOR|#47c16c};height:${ref:Block::Padding_bottom}px;font-size:${ref:Block::Padding_bottom}px;line-height:${ref:Block::Padding_bottom}px;"
class="h-sm-10"
></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Similar to your other post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030766/font-size-email-mobile-is-too-small-on-all-clients?noredirect=1#comment120244647_68030766, I suggest that you send a test of this template so the platform populates your tags and then we can take a look. There could be something in the  tags in the styles or the tags in the content sections that are causing your issues but it isn't obvious at the moment and it's really tough to debug when there is so much we can't see.

Comment: In addition to the above, please supply two screenshots: one of what the problem is, and the second of what the expected result is.